# How to redirect Magento AND show a custom message on the page redirected to?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Been following this little tutorial to create an observer to catch the user logout events and redirect them back to the homepage. It works perfect:

https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/12/making-use-of-observers-in-magento/

However, I need to show a message on the homepage after the user logs out.

So here is the code I have  in the observer to do the redirect and [try to] show the logout message:

```
public function logoutRedirect($observer)
    {
        $observer->getControllerAction()
            ->setRedirectWithCookieCheck('/);
        // Mage::log('tried to redirect ~ did it work?');
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('You are now logged out.');
    }
```

The redirect works, the message does not.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess('You are now logged out.');
```

in place of:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('You are now logged out.');
```

Magento uses **customer/session** for showing message on customer login and logout.